# Array being populated by itself

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm having am issue with an array that seems to be getting populated with my mongoose code by itself. It's making it impossible to populate the array with modified values.

Here's the code:

```
router.get('/in-progress', function(req, res) {
    console.log('exporting');
    var dataset = [];
    Intake.find({}, function(err, intakes) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {      
            /*intakes.forEach(function(intake) {
                dataset.push(
                {
                    //requestName: intake.requestName,
                    requestName: 'Request Name',
                    status: intake.phase
                }
                )
            });*/
            return dataset;       
        }
    }).then((dataset) => {
        console.log(dataset);
        const report = excel.buildExport(
            [
                {
                    heading: inProgressHeading,
                    specification: inProgressSpec,
                    data: dataset
                }
            ]
        );
        res.attachment('requests-in-progress.xlsx');
        return res.send(report);
    });
});
```

As you can see, the logic to push data to "dataset" is commented out, but the console log is logging every Intake that I have in the MongoDB database. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong so that I can push my own values into "dataset"?